# Interfacing PIC16F877A with HC 05 Bluetooth module

Tags: pic

I am a newbiew in embedded hardware.I have a PIC16F877A and a HC 05 Bluetooth module. I want to interface the module with PIC. I am looking for a good tutorial on how to do that... I have googled but couldn't found anything use full. Any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Downvoted because (1) my single search for 'HC05' showed me many good starting point links, such as [this one](http://mbed.org/users/edodm85/notebook/HC-05-bluetooth/) as well as [this one](http://elecfreaks.com/store/download/datasheet/Bluetooth/HC-0305%20serail%20module%20AT%20commamd%20set%20201104%20revised.pdf) and [this one](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-AND-Bluetooth-HC-05-Connecting-easily/), and (2) you haven't explained if your issue is with how to use the HC05, how to use the PIC16F877A or both. If you improve the question (clarify) the downvote can be reversed.

Answer (score 2):

The way to interface anything to a microcontroller is to read the microcontroller datasheet, read the device's datasheet, think about the architecture, then write the code.

The 16F877A is a old microcontroller.  There are many newer ones out that do more, cost less, have more RAM and ROM, and run faster.

I don't know what a "HC 05" bluetooth module is, but you aren't the first to connect a bluetooth module and a micro.  The question is how much of the protocol stack this module does for you.  If it does most everything and you just get a bi-directional stream of data bytes, then the ancient 16F877A may still be useable.  If this module is mostly the radio and the protocol stack is on the micro, then you almost certainly need a bigger micro.

Look around on the Microchip web site.  They have lots of app notes.  Use "bluetooth" as a search keyword and you will likely find something relevant.  Microchip has their own bluetooth modules, and they probably have example firmware that interfaces to them from some of their more advanced micros, like a PIC 32.